# Several forms in a JSP page: how to avoid duplicated ids and tedious parameter processing at the same time?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameters

I have a JSP page that displays a list of items, each one accompanied by a form that allows the user to edit the corresponding item's data. The changes made by the user are processed by a servlet.

Right now, the JSP page produces invalid HTML, because every input of every form share the same id. I can add some suffix to every id, but then the code at the servlet side that gathers all the parameters is not as simple as calling request.getparameter("constantValue") anymore.

I can use request.getParameterNames() and guess which input belongs every id to by its prefix, but I think it looks ugly and it's probably bad code.

Am I missing a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now, the JSP page produces invalid HTML, because every input of
>   every form share the same id

Id's are not considered here, as  `request.getparameter("Name")` requires the attribute name . So make sure that you have unique `name` for the inputs in various form.

> Several forms in a JSP page: how to avoid duplicated ids and tedious
>   parameter processing at the same time?

I believe you have submit button for each form. so that doesnt matter if you are not submitting to the servlet